# Database questions: Primary key and Table access lock

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions, primary-key

1) If I use a primary key on my table does it optimizes the search using that primary key field?

2) For a shared database, while an insertion is made, a query is blocked for a while and after that query is executed after insertion is finished?

Answer (score 2):

Most (all?) major database management systems implement logical primary keys with a physical unique index. The query optimizer can take advantage of that index if it chooses to.

Whether writers block readers depends on the underlying architecture, which varies wildly, and on the transaction isolation level.